# Save PDF from a download link into an object

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, download

Is there a way I can store a pdf file in an object? I have a JSON response with a download url string to a pdf file that I'll have to somehow download and return. I was able to find online a lot of help, but none seemed to do what I want. I don't want to save a file on the drive, I just want it downloaded into memory and sent as a return of a function.
Let's say something like this:

```
static Task<PDFObject> getPDF(string url)
{
    PDFObject obj = await //download pdf from url
    return obj;
}
```

Is this achievable? If need be, I'm open to incorporating a NuGet package in my project. Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What do you mean by "object", exactly? Why not just a simple `Byte[]` buffer (provided it's sized under a couple megabytes, otherwise you probably should save it to a temp file on-disk and then pass around a filename instead of keeping it in-memory)

Comment: @Dai The PDF's are going to be contracts for signers. I cannot guarantee the size of the pdf as I won't be the one making them. But the filename pass is a plausible idea? I could just delete it after sending it to the client.

Comment: If you cannot guarantee the sizes, it is a better practice to write to disk temporarily because someone might try to send a pdf file of few hundred megabytes or more just for fun or testing.

Comment: Just convert your PDF file to base64 and you can embed it in in any object as a string.

Comment: Some things I wanted to say https://justpaste.it/8joto